# Executing 7-zip from VB

Tags: executable, vb.net-2010, 7zip

Alright, I'm having a little trouble getting 7-zip to execute from VB.

Here's my current code:

```
ZipFileName = "\\network\path\PDFs\Test.zip "
PathToPDFs = "\\network\path\PDFs\*.pdf"
Arg1 = "a -tzip"

Process.Start("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" + Arg1 + Zipfilename + PathToPDFs)
```

The error I keep getting is `The system cannot find the file specified` and `Win32Exception was unhandled`

I know my path is correct and there are PDFs in that directory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this

```
Process.Start(
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe",
    Arg1 + Zipfilename + PathToPDFs)
```

First argument must be ONLY executable, while second one must be `ProcessInfo` or a string with arguments.
Tkae a look at this [Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

Comment: This worked perfect. I forgot some spaces I needed but after adding them, all is well, thanks!

Comment: Does all commands need to be setup like this or is running 7-zip a special process?

Comment: @Muhnamana: all commands (except DOS ones, you could need to call them differently)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with gzip like this:

```
Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()

proc.EnableRaisingEvents = False
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "d:\gnuwin32\bin\gzip"
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = My.Settings.GZIPFlags & " " & strDestDir & strFile
proc.Start()
proc.WaitForExit()
```